# add two numpy arrays using lamdify - pass expression as function argument

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify


def test(expr,a,b):

    a_var, b_var = symbols("a b")
    #f = ufuncify((a_var, b_var), expr, backend='numpy')
    f = lambdify( (a_var, b_var), expr, 'numpy')
    return f(a_var, b_var)


a = np.array([2,3])
b = np.array([1,2])
expr = a + b

print(test(expr, a, b))
```

which give me:

```
../anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py:282: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  rational=rational) for x in a])

   File "<string>", line 1
 lambda _Dummy_52,_Dummy_53: ([3 5])                                
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I use the ufuncify :

```
...

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

====== UPDATE ================

One solution I found is to use `expr` like a string and then inside function use `sympify`:

```
data_a = np.array([2,3])
data_b = np.array([1,2])
expr = "data_a + data_b"


def test(expr,data_a, data_b):

        a, b = symbols("data_a data_b")
        expr = sympify(expr)
        f = lambdify( (a, b), expr, 'numpy')
        return f(data_a, data_b)
```

and I am taking:

`[3 5]`

But how can I avoid using the expression as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambdify` converts SymPy expressions into NumPy functions. You are trying to convert a NumPy array into a NumPy function. The arguments to `lambdify` need to be SymPy objects.

You want something like

```
a_var, b_var = symbols("a b")
expr = a_var + b_var
f = lambdify((a_var, b_var), expr, 'numpy')
```

You'll then get

```
>>> a = np.array([2,3])
>>> b = np.array([1,2])
>>> f(a, b)
array([3, 5])
```

The basic code flow for `lambdify` is SymPy expression => NumPy function. To keep things clear in your head and in your code, you should start with just SymPy, and manipulate the expressions until you have a lambdified function. Then use it with your NumPy data. Start with defining symbol names. Then you can define an expression in terms of those symbols, without using a string (for instance, as I have done above). Once you have an expression and the symbols, you create a lambdified function. At that point, you pass NumPy arrays into the function. I recommend using different variable names for SymPy symbols/expressions and NumPy arrays, so that they don't get mixed up. I also recommend using the same variable name for symbols as the symbol names themselves, so that when you print the expression it will appear exactly as you would write it (e.g., below if you `print(expr)`, you will get `a + b`, which is exactly what you would write to get `expr`).

In your updated example, you can use

```
a, b = symbols("a b")
expr = a + b
f = lambdify((a, b), expr, 'numpy')

data_a = np.array([2,3])
data_b = np.array([1,2])
f(data_a, data_b)
```

Note how I start with creating SymPy symbols and a SymPy expression from those symbols. Then I lambdify it. Once it's lambdified, I have the lambdified function (`f`). At this point, I'm not using SymPy at all anymore, just NumPy arrays (the data) and the lambdified function `f`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example in how to pass the expression and the variables as arguments to function?As I have my example?Because, whatever I try it gives an error.Only using expression as a string works as I state in my post.Thanks

Comment: In your example, you are making first a and b symbols and then you are using the expr.In my example, I want to pass expr (an expression) and data (numpy arrays) as arguments.And I must have the `a_var,b_var = symbols("a b")` local in every function.I hope it is clear.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that.So, there is no way to accomplish what I want.Hence, put an expression and the variables to be used as data as arguments to a function.I have to use `symbols` first (outside the function) and define the expression (again outside the function)

Comment: Sure you can, but you either need to always use the same symbol names, or pass the symbol names as arguments to the function.

Comment: Hi, can I ask you?How lambdify works under the hood?It does calculations element by element?Line numpy arrays?So, whatever input I have to lambdify , it will make the calculations element by element?

Comment: @George lambdify converts a SymPy expression into an equivalent numpy function. It is the numpy array object that handles doing calculations element by element. However, in the git master of SymPy, when using numpy as a module with lambdify, all inputs are converted to arrays automatically, so it will effectively work this way for any input.